# Changing rspec version during development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, installation, bundle, rspec-rails

I'm a newbie in Ruby on Rails. I just started with the RoR Tutorial from Michael Hartl ([klick](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)). I'm at 5.2.1 where we learn about Integration_tests.

When I run `rails generate integration_test layout_links` it generates rspec files but when running `rspec spec` I get:

`You have already activated rspec-core 2.6.3, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.x.x` and all tests fail.

and if I play around a little I get `SystemStackError:stack level too deep` and all tests fail.

Probably my Gemsets are messed up or I need another version of rspec-rails running.

Part of my Gemfile.lock looks like:

```
rake (0.9.1)
rb-fsevent (0.4.0)
rspec (2.6.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.6.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.6.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.6.3)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
  diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.18)
  rspec (>= 2.0.0.beta.14)
  webrat (>= 0.7.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
thor (0.14.6)
```

EDIT: Solved. I changed the rspec-rails version to 2.6.1 and added 'webrat' to :development and :test gem sets. Works like a charm... :-)

Answer (score 3):

This can usually be fixed by doing `bundle exec rspec spec` instead of just `rspec spec`

Comment: Or you could `bundle install --binstubs` and just run `bin/rspec spec`, which is basically a shorter way of writing `bundle exec rspec`.

Comment: Useless. Even passing tests don't pass anymore. With `bundle exec rspec spec` I get: `PagesController GET 'home' should be successful
     Failure/Error: response.should be_success
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'last_response' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x000001038df5f0>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in 'block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'`